# MYSQL - Select between range of time

Tags: mysql, time

I want to select all rows between `start_time` and `end_time`. I currently have this query. It works fine but some records are still present although it is not within the range of time indicated:

Structure:

[image]

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_subloading` 
WHERE`start_time` >= '08:00AM' and `end_time`<= '09:00AM';
```

Output:

[image]

What seems to be the problem guys?

Comment: try this `WHERE`start_time` >= '08:00:00' and `end_time`<= '09:00:00';`

Comment: what is datatype of column start_time and end_time

Comment: time - sorry for not indicating it

Comment: @chiragsatapara still the same. not working

Comment: @JohnAnthony, can you share your table structure and data in https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: Records no 3 & 4 would never come in result set because only one condition is satisfied.

Comment: @chiragsatapara sure. i've edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_subloading` 
WHERE`start_time` between CAST('08:00:00' AS time) and 
CAST('09:00:00' AS time) and `end_time` between 
CAST('08:00:00' AS time) and CAST('09:00:00' AS time);
```

Comment: 12:30 is still there. :(

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to eliminate the unwanted time. Don't know if this is an efficient way of doing it but since it does what I wanted, I think it's all good.

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_subloading` 
WHERE `start_time` BETWEEN '08:00AM' and '09:00PM' 
and `end_time` BETWEEN '08:00AM' and '09:00PM'
```

Comment: Yes, it does.  It does what I wanted.

Comment: It says i have to wait 2 days.